# Is a visa required if I want to rent a car in Belarus?

Tags: visas, car-rentals, belarus

I am going to visit Belarus this summer. I am an EU citizen and I will arrive and depart from Minsk International Airport, which is why I don't need a visa.

However, when I want to rent a car for a few days in Belarus. Do the car rentals require visa, or is it enough if I have a passport?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By ‘lend’ do you mean ‘hire’ /‘borrow’?

Comment: Do you mean borrow such as from an acquaintance, or rent/hire from a shop or agency?

Comment: I mean rent from car rental such as Sixt or Avis.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. No extra requirements except valid driver license, take a look here, for example:

[Budget’s long-term car rental rules](http://budgetrent.by/en/long-term-rental/rules/)

As you came to rent office in Minsk, you are implicitly treated as a person legally entered into Belarusian territory.